# Why isnt Geode Geometry Dash Megahack v8 mod not working?

Tags: steam

I'm trying to install Megahack V8 Geode version, but as soon as I open the folder, the installer appears for a second and then disappears. If I manage to click on it, it says that I do not have permission. I have also tried to install the V7.1 Geode version, but it only installs the V7.1 and says that the mod was unable to load.

I was expecting the installation process to guide me, but it didn't work as expected. I tried looking for help on Google, but I could not find any solutions.

I am using Windows 11